# Using TypeScript with Sails

Tags: typescript, sails.js

Is anyone using TypeScript with Sails?  If so, what are you using for external declarations?

I am in the middle of a Sails application project and learned about TypeScript.  I am trying to determine if TypeScript is something I should pursue for this project.  Any info will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

from : https://github.com/balderdashy/sails Sails is built with `node` `connect` `express` and `socket.io`. This means that definition files for these libraries are what you need. All of these are available from the Definitive TypeScript definition repository : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: Following your lead I checked out the mentioned packages.  node, express, and socket.io are indeed in the DefinitelyTyped archive.  However, connect is not.  On further reading I find that connect is really a series of middleware modules, some of which are also in DefinitelyTyped archive but some are not.  Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: just as a bonus, you might consider installing tsd files for async and lodash since both are provided with sails

Answer (score 1):

typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "registry:npm/bluebird#3.5.0+20170314181206",
    "connect": "registry:dt/connect#3.4.0+20160510010627",
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20170118060322",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#4.0.0+20170324160323",
    "sails": "registry:npm/sails#0.12.0+20160610190623",
    "serve-static": "registry:dt/serve-static#1.7.1+20161128184045"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160726072212",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#7.0.0+20170322231424",
    "socket.io": "registry:dt/socket.io#1.4.4+20170313110830"
  }
}
```

welcome controller

```
   /**
     * WelcomeController.ts
     *
     * @description :: Server-side logic for managing Welcomes in TS
     * @help        :: See http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/controllers
     */

    import e = require('express');
    import util = require('util');

    declare const sails: any;

    const WelcomeController = {
      index: function (req: e.Request, res: e.Response, next: Function) {
        console.log('index() from WelcomeController.ts');
        sails.models.welcome.find().limit(1).then((welcome) => {
          /// TODO: add logger
          console.log(`welcome page rendering w/ message ${welcome[0].message}`);
          return res.render('welcome', {
            welcome: welcome[0].message
          });
        }).catch((err:Error) => {
          console.error(err.message);
          return res.render('500', err)
        });


      },
      config: function (req: e.Request, res:e.Response, next:Function) {
        console.log('config() from WelcomeController.ts');
        return res.status(200)
          .send('<h1>sails.config :</h1><pre>' + util.inspect(sails.config) + '<pre>');
      }
    };

    module.exports = WelcomeController;
```

model

```
export class Welcome {
   attributes: any = {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      primaryKey: true
    },
    message: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      defaultsTo: 'default message'
    }
  };
}
```

View

```html
<div class="default-page">
  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="main-title" class="container"></h1>
    <h3 class="container">Message: <code><%= welcome %></code></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="main container clearfix">
```

and so on... I started an example project on git but never finished:

https://github.com/aslanvaroqua/sails-ts